# Persist some JHipster settings globally to save time when creating projects

Tags: jhipster

I'm using JHipster a lot to try out new things

Some settings I usually don't change.
For example: on the internationalization step I usually choose "Englisch" as main language and "German" as translation language.
Also, I want to have some plugins from the marketplace always inside the project.

Can I place a file with some options somewhere so JHipster applies those to all new projects I create?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a jdl-file to persist application settings, too, see: https://github.com/jhipster/jdl-samples (e.g. https://github.com/jhipster/jdl-samples/blob/master/microservice-ecommerce-store-4-apps.jdl).

Here is some documentation, which options you can use for your application: https://www.jhipster.tech/jdl/applications (e.g. `enableTranslation`, `nativeLanguage`, `languages` etc.)